# Get data php with ajax without display it

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is it possible to get data php with Ajax without display them ? Simply stock data in JS variable?
I need this data to manipulate dates but no show it. 
When I tried to simply return data without echo, etc. Data ajax in JS is empty

Ps : sorry my English is bad

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Anything returned to the client via AJAX isn't "displayed" unless you explicitly display it, your client-side code can do whatever you like with the data.  (Though of course it is visible to the user if they look at their network requests.)  It sounds like you've made some attempt which didn't work as expected, perhaps you can elaborate on the problem?  It sounds like maybe you're using `return` where you should be using `echo` to emit output.  `return` is used to return a value from a function, not to emit to the output.

Comment: AJAX means your main page uses JS to make a request to a different PHP script. That PHP script needs to echo out the data you want, but the JS doesn't have to display it. The flow is this: Main PHP renders HTML/JS on Page -> JS on Page uses AJAX to request data from PHP Script 2 -> PHP Script 2 echoes data -> JS on Page now has this data and can do anything with it back on Page, including raw computation without rendering it to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

try it this way

File *.php

```
<?php
    $var_1 = null;
    $var_2 = null;

    /** ... */

    $response = new stdClass;

    $response->var_1 = $var_1;
    $response->var_2 = $var_2;

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

File *.html or *.js

```
<script>
    var state = {};

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getData.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.warn(response);
            state = response;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this answer assumes the use of jQuery, but jQuery certainly isn't required in general.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to pass data from a PHP file to HTML/JS where it happens that your PHP file is also included in the HTML that's why it's displaying the echo (if I understood correctly!)

Using [AJAX PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_php.asp) example from w3school.

HTML sample file:

```
<?php include "PHP_SAMPLE_FILE.php" ?>

<header>
   <meta name="temp_files" content="<?= htmlspecialchars($jsonData) ?>">

<!-- The rest of HTML content -->
```

JS sample file:

```
if (str.length == 0) {
    // do something if there was nothing entered
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if (this.responseText.includes('{')){
            result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            // do something if response is JSON
        } else {
            // do something if response is null
        }
        
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "PHP_SAMPLE_FILE.php?q="+str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

PHP sample file:

```
$q = $_REQUEST["q"] ?? $_POST["q"] ?? "";

$sql = "GET SOMETHING FROM DATABASE";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $json[] = $row; 
    }
}

$jsonData = json_encode($json ?? null);

if($q != ""){
    echo $jsonData;
}
```

What happens exactly is that once the page loads initially it won't display the output of the PHP query as we have surrounded the `echo` with an `if` statement that requires to have query value (q) to search and it shouldn't be empty (""). Of course, assuming that once the page is loaded the data is shared with the client-side through defined PHP variables using various approaches, using a meta tag in the header for instance.

Once the data is received from the PHP file through `echo`, we use the `JSON.parse` function to parse it as in this scenario JS receives it as a string.

Hope that helped :)!